# JavaScript for loop is making the UI unresponsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm making a mailing list script that takes advantage of ajax (async=false) to send emails in chunks.

Basically the cycle is this:

```
var i = 0;
for(i;i<num_rows;i=i+mxt){
    if($("#panic").val()=='1'){
        break;
    }
    perc = (i*100)/num_rows;
    startThread(i,perc);
}
```

Tha panic value is set by a button, the problem is that during the cycle (that works) I can't interact with the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

```
function startThread(i,perc){
l_a = i;
l_b = mxt;

headers = '&mail_from='+mail_from+'&mail_from_name='+mail_from_name+'&mail_subject='+mail_subject;

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST", url: "ajax/thread.php", data: "l_a="+l_a+"&l_b="+l_b+headers, 
    success: function(html){ $("#progressbar").progressbar({value: perc}); },
    async: false
 });
}
```

Comment: Sounds pretty normal to me. How many rows are you processing that way?

Comment: More than 30k total, 100 rows per thread. The thing works like a charm, the only problem is that I would like a way to stop it before it finishes.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `startThread`?

Comment: Edited to include the startThread function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `startThread()` function name is misleading, because JavaScript in web browsers in not only single threaded, but it shares the same thread with the page rendering.

Since you're using `async=false`, the `$.ajax` call become a blocking function, and this blocks the page rendering thread, making the UI unresponsive.

Quoting the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (emphasis added):

> **async**
>
> Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronous (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. **Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.**

Possible solutions:

- Piggyback your data in one JSON object, and send just one `$.ajax` request. If possible use `async=true`.

Comment: No, you are wrong, try to comment out the startThread from the for cycle and you'll see that it's the for cycle not the ajax calls that blocks the UI!

Comment: I want to add something else. If you launch a for cycle with ajax calls (async) you are basically destroying the purpose of this. Each thread send chunks of email then pauses, If I launched 100+ concurrent ajax calls would be the same as sending them all to the smtp server.

Comment: @0plus1: Thanks for the downvote :) ... However, both are blocking. The `$.ajax()` with `async=false` blocks until the server returns a response. That's typically a few tens/hundreds of milliseconds... The `for` loop blocks depending on the number of iterations. Doing a `while (true) { }` blocks the UI... I'm not aware of the logic of your application. Mine was just an attempt to show you why you were having problems.

Comment: @0plus1: Updated my answer with a citation from the jQuery docs.

Comment: @Daniel so basically I'm screwed. I really need to have the synchronous request because they must run sequentially and return a result before moving to the next "thread". I wasn't aware that they completely lock down the browser.

Comment: @0plus1: Is this solution for a public website, or is it going to be deployed in an internal/local environment? Because you could consider [Web Workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Workers) to have multiple threads in JavaScript. Web Workers can do Ajax requests. The only problem is that they are not supported in some popular browsers (IE). That's why I asked if this is a public thing... If you can use Web Workers, you may want to check this related article: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/working-smarter-not-harder/

Comment: @Daniel the solution will only be internal, thank you very much for the hint!